# How to ensure AWS S3 cli file sync fully works without missing files

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm working on a project that takes database backups from MongoDB on S3 and puts them onto a staging box for use for that day. I noticed during a manual run today I got this output. Normally it shows a good copy of each files but today I got a connection reset error or something one of the files, *.15, was not copied over after the operation had completed.

Here is the AWS CLI command that I'm using:

```
aws s3 cp ${S3_PATH} ${BACKUP_PRODUCTION_PATH}/ --recursive
```

And here is an excerpt of the output I got back:

```
download: s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-production.10
 to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.10
download: s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-production.11
 to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.11
download: s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-production.12
 to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.12
download: s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-production.13
 to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.13
download s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-production.14
to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.14
download failed: s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-produc
tion.15 to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.15 ("Connection broken: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", error
(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
download: s3://myorg-mongo-backups-raw/production/daily/2018-09-10/080001/data/s-ds063192-a1/myorg-production/myorg-production.16
to ../../data/db/myorg-production/myorg-production.16
```

How can I ensure that the data from the given S3 path was fully copied over to the target path without any connection issues, missing files, etc? Is the `sync` command for the AWS tool a better option? Or should I try something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the awscli supports an s3 sync option which might be preferable to an s3 cp. I'd hope, but don't know for sure, that in either case, a connection error resulting in a file being skipped would result in a non-zero return code from the awscli, allowing you to decide how to respond (maybe re-run the sync, for example).